# Why would waitpid in Perl return wrong exit code?

Tags: perl, exit-code, waitpid

I get wrong exit code from waitpid and I can't figure out why. Could someone give me some ideas?

Here what I do:

1. I start my child process with `open2`
2. then I wait for it to finish with `waitpid`
3. get exit code using `$?`

It always returns with -1 no mater what I return from child process. I check with VS debugger that my program returns an exit code of 0. VS says something like this:

```
The program '[3256] Test.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I made sure that pids match.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post your perl code, using "sleep" instead of your program?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just figured it out. waitpid has 3 stages:

```
 1. process is running:    waitpid returns 0;   $? is -1
 2. process is exiting:    waitpid returns pid; $? is actual exit code
 3. process doesn't exist: waitpid returns -1;  $? is -1
```

so when doing something like while(waitpid($pid, WNOHANG) >= 0) exit code must be retrieved once cycle before that.

Comment: Or  you could just call waitpid($pid, 0) and it will wait until the program has exited.

Comment: Ah - yes waitpid only reports the result once.

Comment: Paul: yes that would work, but I can't block on that, because I need to read log files while the process is running.

Answer (score 3):

From the [waitpid man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid.html):

> Note that on some systems, a return value of "-1" could mean
>   that child processes are being automatically reaped.
>   See [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) for details, and for other examples.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using waitpid, you should just close the filehandle.  (I assume the "open2" in your question is a typo, and you meant "open")

Comment: open2 (see IPC::Open2) is a call that allows you to send input to and receive output from the same program

Answer (score 0):

Works for me (Windows):

```
use IPC::Open3;
use POSIX ':sys_wait_h';
use Time::HiRes;

$|++;

my ($fin, $fh, $pid);
$pid = open3($fin, $fh, 0, 'ping', '8.8.8.8') or die('error');

my @lines = ();
while (1) {
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        push(@lines, $line);
        print('+');
    }
    print("\nret: `$?`\n"), last if waitpid($pid, WNOHANG) <= 0;
    Time::HiRes::usleep(100000);
    $fh->clearerr();
}
waitpid($pid, 0);
print("\nret: `$?`\n");
```

Will output:

```
++++++++++++
ret: `-1`

ret: `0`
```